# Why Axios causes InterceptorManager error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

The next code
`const axios = require("axios");`
in Typescript class provoces an error with message:

> InterceptorManager.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'forEach' of object '#'
> at eval (InterceptorManager.js:44)
> at Object../node_modules/axios/lib/core/InterceptorManager.js (:468:1)
> at **webpack_require** (:20:30)
> at eval (Axios.js:5)
> at Object../node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js (:456:1)
> at **webpack_require** (:20:30)
> at eval (axios.js:5)
> at Object../node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js (:408:1)
> at **webpack_require** (:20:30)
> at eval (index.js:1)

I have Axios of 0.19.2.

What can cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

**I try this and it work**
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import axios from "axios";

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-comp',
  templateUrl: './test-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-comp.component.css']
})
export class TestCompComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  testCall(){
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

}

HTML CODE 
<button (click)="testCall()">Call http</button>
```

Comment: I tried this way too, but the same error... and "import * as axios from "axios"" too

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It lies in "use strict" mode in bundles.
After solving problem, import works fine.